# RegEx to split and remember match (elegantly)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, str-replace

I am trying to write a parser for API response form Wikipedia. It is really cluttered and I have resorted to good old RegEx to sanitize most stuff. I am however stuck at this. Consider a string:

```
 var a ="[[December 1]]  A triangular [[Conjunction (astronomy)|conjunction]] formed by a new Moon, Venus and Jupiter is a [[Conjunction (astronomy)#2008|prominent sight]] in the evening sky. [[December 2]]";
```

I want the text from this string to be:

```
 "December 1  A triangular conjunction formed by a new Moon, Venus and Jupiter is a prominent sight in the evening sky. December 2"
```

I am having trouble handling the square brackets `[,]`. I can not just remove them because the links are represented like this:

```
 [[Conjunction (astronomy)#2008|prominent sight]]
```

In such situations I would want to remove the part "Conjunction (astronomy)#2008" because the actual string shown on the webpage is "prominent sight". Is there an elegant way to handle both these cases in one `str.replace(//gi,"")` query in JavaScript?

I do this `a.replace(/\[\[.*\|/gi, "");` and it yields:

```
 "prominent sight]] in the evening sky. [[December 2]]"
```

So clearly, I need to match continuous opening and closing brackets `[[]]` as the pattern and then remember the match I suppose. I am not sure how to go about this but I hope the two cases are clear:

1. `[[ normal word ]]` -> normal word
2. `[[ some definition blah |foo bar]]` -> foo bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with callback with following RegEx

```
/\[{2}([\w\s()#]+)(?:\|([\w\s]+))?\]{2}/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zD7lZ8/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

1. `\[{2}([\w\s()#]+)`:

   - `\[{2}`: Matches `[[`
   - `([\w\s()#]+)`: Matches any alphanumeric character, `_`, spaces, `(`, `)`, and `#` one or more number of times and put it in first captured group.
2. `(?:\|([\w\s]+))?\]{2}`:

   - `(?:`: Non-capturing group
   - `\|`: Matches pipe symbol `|`
   - `([\w\s]+)`: Match alphanumeric characters, `_`, and spaces one or more time and put in second captured group
   - `\]{2}`: Match `]]`

**RegEx Visualization**<sup>Easier to understand</sup>

[image: Visualization]

**Demo:**

```js
var regex = /\[{2}([\w\s()#]+)(?:\|([\w\s]+))?\]{2}/g;
var str = "[[December 1]]  A triangular [[Conjunction (astronomy)|conjunction]] formed by a new Moon, Venus and Jupiter is a [[Conjunction (astronomy)#2008|prominent sight]] in the evening sky. [[December 2]]";

str = str.replace(regex, function(c, m1, m2) {
  return m2 ? m2 : m1;
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + str + '</pre>';
```

---

> This regex is not working for the string I mentioned in the question, but it is working for the string I put up in the comment
>
> "A [[2008 Iwate-Miyagi Nairiku earthquake|6.9 magnitude earthquake]] in Iwate Prefecture, Japan, kills 12 and injures more than 400."

You can use following RegEx.

[`\[{2}([^|]*?)(?:\|(.*?))?\]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/zD7lZ8/3)

Comment: **Note:** To allow more characters in the brackets, add those in `([\w\s()#]+)`. Ex. to allow `-`, `([\w\s()#-]+)`. Depending on the character, it might need to be escaped by preceding with `\`.

Comment: Tushar, thanks for the detailed answer. I tried your regex on `"A [[2008 Iwate-Miyagi Nairiku earthquake|6.9 magnitude earthquake]] in Iwate Prefecture, Japan, kills 12 and injures more than 400."` Doesn't seem to be working in this case. Can you point out why?

Comment: @VivekPradhan, please read the above comment. As the string contains `-`, you need to add those characters in the regex.

Comment: I modified the regex to `var regex = /\[{2}([\w\s()#-]+)(?:\|([\w\s]+))?\]{2}/g;` Added `-` like you mentioned. But it's still not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @VivekPradhan Use [`\[{2}([\w\s()#\.-]+)(?:\|(.+))?\]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/zD7lZ8/2)

Comment: This regex is not working for the string I mentioned in the question, but it is working for the string I put up in the comment..

Comment: I have not accepted the answer yet because the solution is not yet entirely generic I suppose. I will accept it as soon as that is fixed, so that other's in a similar problem might not get stuck.

Comment: @VivekPradhan That's fine. I've updated the answer(check the bottom regex), please check all the possible scenarios and then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\[(?:([^|]*)|[^|]*\|(.*?))\]\]
```

You can use this and replace by `$1$2`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/9